# Better approach to queuing reports

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services

Say I have a windows service that runs a method to generate reports.

For example say I have a Reports table that has the report path, status, name of report, parameters etc.

When a user clicks the generate report button a new entry will be added to the table with a status of queued. The service will take queued reports, generate the report, update the status and set the path of the completed report.

The 2 ways I can think of doing this is to either poll the table for queued reports (something like):

```
TimerCallback callback = new TimerCallback(RunQuery);
this.QueryTimer = new Timer(callback, null, 1000, 10000);

public void RunQuery(object obj)
{                           
    //find reports with status of queued, 
    //loop through them and generate reports            
}
```

Or create a file with the ReportId and use a FileSystemWatcher to determine which reports to run (something like):

```
private void FileSystemWatcher1_Created(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    ReportStack.Push(e.FullPath);
    Thread TR = new Thread(RunQuery);
    TR.Start();
}

public void RunQuery()
{                           
    string filePath = Convert.ToString(ReportStack.Pop()); 
    GenerateReport(filePath);
    ...
}
```

A downside to the 1st method is that I need to specify a poll time and reports don't generate instantly as they are queued. A downside to the second method is the small hassle of creating and deleting files, setting up permission for the app to write to a shared folder etc.

Is there a way to get the service to automatically kick off reports as they are placed into the report table (something like a DatabaseTableWatcher!) or another better way to do this?

Comment: Have you considered sql server notification service? http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/sqlns.aspx

Comment: @Pleun has this not been superseeded by CEP (which I know nothing about!)? That codeproject page is from 2002 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hovsep/archive/2009/08/23/notification-services-has-died-welcome-sql-server-2008-r2-complex-event-processing-cep-technology.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL triggers or Message Queuing

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

So when a record is inserted into the table you can fire off an action such as calling a sproc.

Personally I like your first polling approach.

Comment: The problem with triggers is that I need it to run .NET code and not just a stored proc - is it possible to do this? I'll probably end up using the polling approach but my only concern is the delay for users (ie waiting 20 seconds before they see that their report is generating). I could increase the polling time but would need to test the effects of a database hit every x seconds.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [Microsoft Message Queuing (MSMQ)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms711472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? MSMQ creates and manages message queues at the operating system level. It seems a perfect match for your application.